# Pass in array to salesforce platform event?

Tags: apex, platform-event

I am using platform events and trying to send in some parameters to the platform event from an external system. One of the parameters is an array, but I am getting an error from salesforce.   The only data types available when creating a field on a platform event object are "checkbox, number, date, date/time, text, textarea".

Below is the error I am getting:

```
[{:message Cannot deserialize instance of textarea from START_ARRAY value 
[line:1, column:160], :errorCode JSON_PARSER_ERROR}]
```

Things work fine for things like strings and simple values, but hoping for someone to confirm if there is a way to pass an array of data in.

Comment: Can you post some detail? If you're trying to put the array into a text field, you must format it as a string, not as an array

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. You can't send parameters in a single platform event.

You can either insert multiple events or a single event with your data serialized in a JSON (in one of the text fields). On the second approach you'll still need a trigger on the platform event to deserialize the data before handling it.

The caveat with the second approach is the limitation of the text field size, which is around 131k characters.

Comment: I posted this issue to the Platform Events Success Community as accepting arbitrary Json was a good use case for Platform Events - it was acknowledged as 'a previously registered suggestion' . I did an ugly hack wherein my platform event sobject had three fields `Json0__c`, `Json1__c`, `Json2__c`; ea 131072 and it was the responsibility of the publisher to span long json and the subscriber to unspan.  Yuck.